# Got a component with the name "" for screen ""

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So im making an app with authentication flow and followed the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)
now  even though there was no user in the state the navigation didn't move to login screen so i changed the condition for rendering and now the i'm on Login page except there's no output and following error

> Got a component with the name 's' for the screen 'Settings'.Got a component with the name 'l' for the screen 'Login'.Got a component with the name 'p' for the screen 'Home'. React Components must start with an uppercase letter. If you're passing a regular function and not a component, pass it as children to 'Screen' instead. Otherwise capitalize your component's name.

**App.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {NativeBaseProvider, Box} from 'native-base';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {theme} from './theme';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  signInWithEmailPassword,
  signOutFunc,
  signUpWithEmailPassword,
  signInWithGoogle,
} from './components/auth/helper';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Settings from './components/core/Settings';
import Home from './components/core/Home';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export default function App({navigation}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_USER':
          return {...prevState, user: action.user, isLoading: false};
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {...prevState, isSignout: false, user: action.user};
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {...prevState, isSignout: true, user: null};
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      user: null,
    },
  );
  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (data, type) => {
        let user;
        if (type === 'email') {
          user = await signInWithEmailPassword(data.email, data.password);
        } else {
          user = await signInWithGoogle();
        }

        if (user) {
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', user: user});
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
      },
      signOut: async type => {
        try {
          signOutFunc('google');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        try {
          signOutFunc('email');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        dispatch({type: 'SIGN_OUT'});
      },
      signUp: async (data, type) => {
        let user;
        if (type === 'email') {
          user = await signUpWithEmailPassword(data.email, data.password);
        } else {
          user = await signInWithGoogle();
        }
        if (user) {
          try {
            const user = await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              'user',
              JSON.stringify(data),
            );
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', user: user});
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
      },
    }),
    [],
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let user;
      try {
        user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        console.log(user);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      dispatch({type: 'RESTORE_USER', user: user});
    };
    bootstrapAsync();
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
        <NavigationContainer
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}>
          {state.user !== null ? (
            <Tab.Navigator>
              <Tab.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
          ) : (
            <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
              <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import EmailSignUp from './EmailSingUp';
import GoogleSignin from './GoogleSignIn';

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <GoogleSignin />
      <EmailSignUp />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Setting.js**

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {AuthContext} from '../../App';
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';

const Settings = () => {
  const {signOut} = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Settings</Text>

      <Button onPress={() => signOut()}>Sign Out </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Android. I realised that my "JS Minify" setting was checked which loads the JavaScript bundle with `minify=true`.

It might be the same issue in your case.

In order to disable this settings, open the Developer menu, select "**Settings**" and then unselect "**JS Minify**" option.

Close your app/uninstall it first to ensure that you no longer have this issue.